# SpringDoc OpenAPI swagger MergeAnnotations error

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openui, springdoc-ui

I am trying to configure OpenAPI with swagger to my existing non-spring boot application.

Spring v.5.1.8.RELEASE
SpringDoc v.1.4.6
Spring-boot v.2.3.2.RELEASE

[Open doc and swagger with spring mv](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-to-integrate-open-api-3-with-spring-project-not-spring-boot)

My application is not spring boot enable that’s why I have following dependencies in my Pom copied from article linked above

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>last.version</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My Spring mvc project already has servlet context configuration so I assumed I only need to register/import open api and swagger configuration files.

So I did the following

```
@EnableMvc
@Configuration
@import({org.springdoc.ui.SwaggerConfig.class,
                org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties.class, org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiOAuthProperties.class,
                org.springdoc.webmvc.core.SpringDocWebMvcConfiguration.class,
                org.springdoc.webmvc.core.MultipleOpenApiSupportConfiguration.class,
                org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.class, org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfigProperties.class,
                org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.class

 @Bean
Public OpenAPI(){
return new OpenAPI();
}
```

When I run my application I gets the following error

**“Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatgedTypeMetadata.getAnnotations()/Lorg/springframework/core/annotations/MergeAnnotations”**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused due to incompatible version of spring mvc and spring-boot